# ExpressJS middleware for logs

Tags: node.js, express

I'd like to create a middleware to save logs in my database.

But in my below middleware, any URL is saving, I don't want to save "favicon.ico" for example or "src of images"... I just want to save URLs and POSTs that are triggered by the user.

```
  server.app.use(function(request, response, next) {

    LogModel.create({
      type: request.method,
      url: response.statusCode + ' : ' + request.url
    }).then(function() {
      console.log(colors.green('URL : ' + request.originalUrl));
    });
    next();
  });
```

**Result :**

[image]

**Expected result :**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could of course check the request path manually inside your middleware and skip the logic for specific paths by calling `next()`. An alternative is to use a package like [express-unless](https://github.com/jfromaniello/express-unless) which allows you to control your middleware with various options. In your case you could specify the paths you want to skip:

```
const unless = require('express-unless');
const app = express();

const loggingMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
    LogModel.create(...);
    next();
};
loggingMiddleware.unless = unless;

app.use(loggingMiddleware.unless({
    path: [
        '/favicon.ico' // add more paths if needed
    ]
}));
```

Comment: Thank you i'll try with this module. I hope i could use REGEXs.